# How to implement a takeWhile-like function using Conduit combinators?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'm trying to implement a function that combines the ideas of `groupBy` and `takeWhile`, as well as uses the latter internally. Specifically, it will group all elements that consecutively return `True` on the current predicate as a list, then it will proceed to do the same with the next predicate, and so on:

```
   takeWhileGrouped :: (Monad m, MonoFoldable mono) =>
      ([Element mono -> Bool]) -> ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
    takeWhileGrouped preds = go preds
      where
        go (pred:nextPreds) = yield (goIter pred) >> go nextPreds
        goIter pred = takeWhile pred .| sinkList
```

It's entirely likely this implementation suffers other issues, but at this stage I'm getting a compilation error that I'm not sure how to proceed with (why can't `mono0` be identified with `mono`?); is this due to the lack of using some language extension, or is there another issue?

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Element mono0’ with ‘Element mono’
      Expected type: [Element mono -> Bool]
                     -> ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
        Actual type: [Element mono0 -> Bool]
                     -> ConduitT (Element mono0) [Element mono0] m ()
      NB: ‘Element’ is a non-injective type family
      The type variable ‘mono0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘takeWhileGrouped’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In the type signature:
        takeWhileGrouped :: (Monad m, MonoFoldable mono) =>
                            ([Element mono -> Bool])
                            -> ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
    |
140 | takeWhileGrouped :: (Monad m, MonoFoldable mono) =>
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

**Update 1**

Enabling `AllowAmbiguousTypes` does make the error go away, but I'll note that in [the combinators library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.1.1/docs/src/Data.Conduit.Combinators.html) this appears to be unnecessary.

Now the real issues show themselves:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘ConduitT a0 c0 m0 [b0]’
                     with ‘[Element mono]’
      Expected type: ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
        Actual type: ConduitT
                       (Element seq0) (ConduitM a0 c0 m0 [b0]) m ()
    • In the expression: go preds
      In an equation for ‘takeWhileGrouped’:
          takeWhileGrouped preds
            = go preds
            where
                go (pred : nextPreds) = yield (goIter pred) >> go nextPreds
                goIter pred = takeWhile pred .| sinkList
    • Relevant bindings include
        preds :: [Element mono -> Bool]
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:143:18)
        takeWhileGrouped :: [Element mono -> Bool]
                            -> ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:143:1)
    |
143 | takeWhileGrouped preds = go preds
    |                          ^^^^^^^^


    • Couldn't match type ‘seq -> seq’ with ‘ConduitT a b m1 ()’
      Expected type: ConduitM a b m1 ()
        Actual type: seq -> seq
    • Probable cause: ‘takeWhile’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of ‘(.|)’, namely ‘takeWhile pred’
      In the expression: takeWhile pred .| sinkList
      In an equation for ‘goIter’:
          goIter pred = takeWhile pred .| sinkList
    • Relevant bindings include
        pred :: Element seq -> Bool
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:146:12)
        goIter :: (Element seq -> Bool) -> ConduitM a c m1 [b]
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:146:5)
    |
146 |     goIter pred = takeWhile pred .| sinkList
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Update 2**

I was using the wrong `takeWhile`, now using `CC.takeWhile` from Conduit Cominators, I'm currently left with:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘ConduitT
                             (Element mono) c0 m0 [Element mono]’
                     with ‘[Element mono]’
      Expected type: ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
        Actual type: ConduitT
                       (Element mono) (ConduitM (Element mono) c0 m0 [Element mono]) m ()
    • In the expression: go preds
      In an equation for ‘takeWhileGrouped’:
          takeWhileGrouped preds
            = go preds
            where
                go (pred : nextPreds) = yield (goIter pred) >> go nextPreds
                goIter pred = CM.takeWhile pred .| sinkList
    • Relevant bindings include
        preds :: [Element mono -> Bool]
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:144:18)
        takeWhileGrouped :: [Element mono -> Bool]
                            -> ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:144:1)
    |
144 | takeWhileGrouped preds = go preds
    |                          ^^^^^^^^
```

**Update 3**

Had a few combinator API issues to fix, but at least one still remains:

```
takeWhileGrouped :: forall m mono. (Monad m, MonoFoldable mono) =>
  ([Element mono -> Bool]) -> ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
takeWhileGrouped preds = go preds
  where
    go (pred:nextPreds) = yieldM (goIter pred) >> go nextPreds
    go [] = yield []
    goIter :: (Element mono -> Bool) -> m ([Element mono])
    goIter pred = (CC.takeWhile pred) .| sinkList & runConduitRes
```

Unexpectedly, I have a `()` popping up in the input to `takeWhile`:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Element mono’ with ‘()’
      Expected type: () -> Bool
        Actual type: Element mono -> Bool
    • In the first argument of ‘CC.takeWhile’, namely ‘pred’
      In the first argument of ‘(.|)’, namely ‘(CC.takeWhile pred)’
      In the first argument of ‘(&)’, namely
        ‘(CC.takeWhile pred) .| sinkList’
    • Relevant bindings include
        pred :: Element mono -> Bool
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:148:12)
        goIter :: (Element mono -> Bool) -> m [Element mono]
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:148:5)
        preds :: [Element mono -> Bool]
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:144:18)
        takeWhileGrouped :: [Element mono -> Bool]
                            -> ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:144:1)
    |
148 |     goIter pred = (CC.takeWhile pred) .| sinkList & runConduitRes
    |                                 ^^^^
```

**Update 4**

After fixing some more logic and type errors, which was really aided by adding an internal type annotation `(CC.takeWhile curPred :: ConduitT (Element mono) (Element mono) m ())`, I have something that compiles, but still needs testing:

```
takeWhileGrouped :: forall m mono. (Monad m, MonoFoldable mono) =>
  ([Element mono -> Bool])
  -> ConduitT () (Element mono) m ()
  -> ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
takeWhileGrouped preds conIn = go preds
  where
    go (curPred:nextPreds) = yieldM (goIter curPred) >> go nextPreds
    go [] = yield []
    goIter :: (Element mono -> Bool) -> m ([Element mono])
    goIter curPred = conIn .| CC.takeWhile curPred .| sinkList & runConduit
```

Comment: I'd still like to know how to implement this using `await`

Answer (score 1):

I came to the eventual conclusion that, if I wanted to implement this component, [I couldn't do it in terms of component composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107971/why-is-there-an-unexpected-expected-type-of-in-this-conduit-composition-fu/58124544#58124544) (fusion).

Here's an implementation that seems to work:

```
takeWhileGrouped :: forall m mono. Monad m =>
  [Element mono -> Bool] -> ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
takeWhileGrouped preds = start
  where
    start = await >>= maybe (return ()) (loop preds [])
    loop :: [(Element mono) -> Bool] -> [Element mono] -> (Element mono)
      -> ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
    loop [] _ _ = yield []
    loop curPreds@(predF:predRest) accum x =
        await >>= maybe (yield accumX) go
      where
        accumX = if predF x then x:accum else accum
        go y = if predF y then loop curPreds accumX y
               else yield accumX >> loop predRest [] y
```

This design was influenced by the most similar function I knew of (though from a deprecated library), [groupBy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.1.1/docs/src/Data.Conduit.List.html#groupBy).