# Why is there an unexpected "expected type" of () in this conduit composition (fusion)?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I have the following conduit components that are being fused together:

```
awaitVals () :: ConduitT (Element mono) (Element mono) m ()
intermTmp :: forall o. (Element mono -> Bool) -> ConduitT (Element mono) o m ([Element mono])
```

The fusion occurs like: `awaitVals () .| intermTmp curPred`.

According to the fuse function (`.|`), I think the types should be OK here. Fuse is:

```
(.|) :: Monad m
     => ConduitT a b m ()
     -> ConduitT b c m r
     -> ConduitT a c m r
```

Here's the entire function definition:

```
takeWhileGrouped :: forall m mono. (Monad m, MonoFoldable mono) =>
  ([Element mono -> Bool])
  -> ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
takeWhileGrouped preds = go preds
  where
    go (curPred:nextPreds) = yieldM (goIter curPred) >> go nextPreds
    go [] = yield []
    intermTmp :: forall o. (Element mono -> Bool) -> ConduitT (Element mono) o m ([Element mono])
    intermTmp curPred = CC.takeWhile curPred .| sinkList
    goIter :: (Element mono -> Bool) -> m ([Element mono])
    goIter curPred =
      (awaitVals () :: ConduitT (Element mono) (Element mono) m ())
        .| (intermTmp curPred) & runConduit

awaitVals :: forall a m. Monad m => () -> ConduitT a a m ()
awaitVals _ = do
  nextValMay <- await
  case nextValMay of
    Just val -> do
      yield val
      awaitVals ()
    Nothing -> pure ()
```

And here is the error:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Element mono’ with ‘()’
      Expected type: ConduitM () () m ()
        Actual type: ConduitT (Element mono) (Element mono) m ()
    • In the first argument of ‘(.|)’, namely
        ‘(awaitVals () :: ConduitT (Element mono) (Element mono) m ())’
      In the first argument of ‘(&)’, namely
        ‘(awaitVals () :: ConduitT (Element mono) (Element mono) m ())
           .| (intermTmp curPred)’
      In the expression:
        (awaitVals () :: ConduitT (Element mono) (Element mono) m ())
          .| (intermTmp curPred)
          & runConduit
    • Relevant bindings include
        curPred :: Element mono -> Bool
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:151:12)
        goIter :: (Element mono -> Bool) -> m [Element mono]
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:151:5)
        intermTmp :: forall o.
                     (Element mono -> Bool)
                     -> ConduitT (Element mono) o m [Element mono]
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:149:5)
        preds :: [Element mono -> Bool]
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:144:18)
        takeWhileGrouped :: [Element mono -> Bool]
                            -> ConduitT (Element mono) [Element mono] m ()
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Conduits.hs:144:1)
    |
151 |     goIter curPred = (awaitVals () :: ConduitT (Element mono) (Element mono) m ()) .| (intermTmp curPred) & runConduit
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't understand why the expected type disagrees with the actual type.
Here's a more general question that I haven't totally wrapped up, but it does have a working solution near the end (but it doesn't use fuse to compose conduits at the outermost level): [How to implement a takeWhile-like function using Conduit combinators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104485/how-to-implement-a-takewhile-like-function-using-conduit-combinators)
I should probably wait to look at this after having slept a reasonable amount, but I was very curious about this...

Comment: I just noticed there was a `ConduitM` in the message, but apparently `type ConduitM = ConduitT`, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: I'm coming to realize that the issue relates `runConduit` (and all variants thereof) expecting `()` at the input position, and relatedly, I have no "source" that would have unit in the input position as currently written .... hmm

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `runConduit` requires `()` to be in the input type of the conduit component it is passed. But that is clearly not what we have here: we need a source for that, and we just don't have one in this context. Then we need to implement the function without using `runConduit`, so we can no longer construct intermediary conduits. See [How to implement a takeWhile-like function using Conduit combinators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104485/how-to-implement-a-takewhile-like-function-using-conduit-combinators) for an implementation that works.

**Note**: I came to this conclusion after playing out with the following conduits that made it a bit easier to see what was happening with types and variation in composition. The commented out examples have trouble compiling.

```
testCondComposedSink :: forall i o m. Monad m => ConduitT i o m [i]
testCondComposedSink = awaitVals () .| sinkList

testCondComposedTakeW :: forall i m. Monad m => ConduitT i i m ()
testCondComposedTakeW = awaitVals () .| CC.takeWhile (\_ -> True)

testCondComposedAll :: forall i o m. Monad m => ConduitT i o m [i]
testCondComposedAll = awaitVals () .| CC.takeWhile (\_ -> True) .| sinkList

takeWhileSinkList :: forall i o m. Monad m => (i -> Bool) -> ConduitT i o m [i]
takeWhileSinkList predicate = CC.takeWhile predicate .| sinkList

testCondComposedAll2 :: forall i o m. Monad m => ConduitT i o m [i]
testCondComposedAll2 = awaitVals () .| takeWhileSinkList (\_ -> True)

-- testCondComposedAll2Run ::  forall i m. Monad m => m [i]
-- testCondComposedAll2Run = testCondComposedAll2 & runConduit

-- takeWhileSinkList2 :: forall i m. Monad m => (i -> Bool) -> ConduitT () Void m [i]
-- takeWhileSinkList2 predicate = CC.takeWhile predicate .| sinkList

-- testCondComposedAll3 :: forall i o m. Monad m => ConduitT () o m [i]
-- testCondComposedAll3 = awaitVals () .| takeWhileSinkList2 (\_ -> True)

-- testCondComposedAll3Run ::  forall i m. Monad m => m [i]
-- testCondComposedAll3Run = testCondComposedAll3 & runConduit

-- testCondDownsteram :: forall i o r m. Monad m => () -> ConduitT i o m r
-- testCondDownsteram = undefined
```